# XCode 15 view controller glitched when presented first time after installing bulid on device

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

Today I have faced the problem after bulding app on device, modal presented view controller glitched. Intresting that it throws only ONE TIME after app builded on device and then it's work correct every time (after fully closing app it's work correct to). But if app installed from ipa on device it's work correct even for the first time after installing.
My suggestion that if the view controller have issue with code base, it would be glitched every time.
May be it's Xcode 15 issue ?

i've tried DispatchQueue.main.async { self.present(vc, animated: true) } (no glitch, but 2s delay at first presenting)